# Computer science FLOPs question (complexity): We have $100$ vectors, each with $10^5$ elements.

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, computational-complexity, floating-point

Our numerical analysis textbook has this problem:

> How many bytes does it take to store $100$ vectors of length $10^5$? How
>   many flops does it take to form a linear combination of them (with $100$ nonzero
>   coefficients)? About how long would this take on a computer capable of carrying
>   out $1 Gflop/s$?

Okay, so first off, my confusion is regarding whether I should be interpreting the "Giga" prefix to mean $10^9$ or its rough binary approximation of $2^{30}$. That makes a difference, right? So, here's my attempt:

---

**Part 1**

Assume we're working with a $32$-bit machine and that each element of a vector requires $4$ bytes. A single vector has $10^5$ elements, meaning it requires $4 \times 10^5$ bytes. We have $10^2 = 100$ of these vectors, giving us a total of $4 \times 10^7$ bytes ($40,000,000$).

(Would this be $2^{25} =33,554,432$ in binary?)

**Part 2**

Okay, this one was the toughest in my opinion. Please let me know if my work is correct.

Suppose we have this linear combination:

$a_1\vec{v_1} + a_2\vec{v_2} + ... + a_{100}\vec{v_{100}}$

Now, let's focus on just the first term:

$a_1\vec{v_1}$ requires that you distribute the constant to $10^5$ terms. This is $10^5$ flops.

Now, extending that, we have $100$ of these scalar-vector terms. So that's $10^2 * 10^5 = 10^7$ flops.

Moreover, once we have done that, we have to add each resulting vector's terms in a component-wise fashion.

This requires that we add the first component of $\vec{v_1}$ with the first component of $\vec{v_2}$ with the first component of ... $\vec{v_{100}}$.

In other words, we have to add $100$ components, but each vector has $10^5$ components "stacked" vertically. So that's another $10^2 \times 10^5 = 10^7$ flops.

Giving me an answer of $10^{14}$. I am not sure if this is correct. Moreover, I'm not sure if $2^{46}$ is the correct binary approximation.

**Part 3**

This one's straightforward, but it assumes my answers to the first two parts are correct.

Also, I am again using an approximation of $2^{30}$ for the giga term.

I got $\frac{2^{46}}{2^{30}} = 2^{16} = 65,536$ seconds.

---

Note: If I leave things in their decimal form, I get an answer of $10^5 = 100,000$ seconds. So I guess that's sort of close?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's the question here? Not to sound rude but it seems like you have the answer.

Comment: Add the proof verification tag if you want your work to be checked.

Comment: @theREALyumdub Sorry, yep, I'm looking for a verification of my work.

Comment: @AlexsandrH Ok, that might help get you more attention. But it's still unclear to me what you are asking. Does "Yes" qualify as an answer (I have to look more, but supposing)? This is after all a question and answer site.

Comment: @theREALyumdub No, I added specific questions for each part of the problem. Some are not questions (e.g., "I'm not sure if this is correct") but can be readily interpreted as one. I'm not sure where else I could ask this; our instructor and TA are not particularly helpful :/

Comment: The quality of your work suggests otherwise. Give me a moment and I will see if I can post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me the way you are proposing this solution struggles in two ways. For one thing, some of your calculations are a bit off, and for another, binary to decimal conversions are a little tricky.

Maybe for this sort of problem it would be easiest to simply put everything in the same base, and convert later. Let's assume decimal because the problem is entirely worded that way, except for mention of bytes. You can convert to binary if that's explicitly required afterwards. See [this (very old) link](http://www.dewassoc.com/kbase/hard_drives/binary_v_decimal_measurement.htm) for a good discussion how.

I would recommend you solve this problem entirely mathematically, and I'll give you the mathematics answer since we are on this part of SE.

### Part 1

This part looks fine to me as it is. You've even been thorough to move from element to vector to number of vectors.

### Part 2

This also almost looks good to me.

> In other words, we have to add 100 components, but each vector has $ 10^5 $ components "stacked" vertically. So that's another $ 10^2 × 10^5 = 10^7 $ flops.

Good point, though technically you are only adding 99 times, about the same. But then you say

> Giving me an answer of $ 10^{14} $. I am not sure if this is correct.

It's not, because you aren't adding separately for all multiplications. In fact what you are doing is multiplying them all, and then adding. This is like $ O(n^2) + O(n^2) $ and not $ O(n^2) * O(n^2) $. So you get $ 10^7 + 10^7 = 2 * 10^7 $, where one is from adding and one from multiplying.

### Part 3

This answer doesn't make sense because of the incorrect estimate from Part 2. It may help to use units when you have to measure times as well as data, but your method is correct. You should get an answer of $ 10^7 / 10^9 $ seconds, assuming a Gigabyte is a billion bytes, which it often is less than in storage practice.

Comment: Oh, oops, you're right that it should be $2*10^7$ for part two. My fried brain computed that as $10^{14}$. Also, nice catch on the $99$ additions. For Part 3, I'm assuming we're disregarding the $2$ because it's just a constant and doesn't contribute much, right?

Comment: Or rather, part two should be $199 \times 10^5$, or $1.9 \times 10^7$, right?

Comment: It would accurately be closer to 2* 10^7, but the need for accuracy depends on context. Why ask me? Go and see what the book specifies for the problem. If the chapter before talks about big O notation, that's a good hint those constants don't matter, just say 10^7. If, on the other hand, this is related to something else, maybe your instructor or TA would have a better idea.